# IOS / Android: Can I retrieve clickthrough data from inside an app?

Tags: android, ios, analytics, flurry, click-through

I'm trying to find a way to figure out how to retrieve clickthrough information to figure out which ad / link was clicked to direct a person to download it.

Say we have the following situation:

1. User sees an ad for the app.
2. They click it
3. It directs them to the app store, and they download it from there.
4. They run the app

Is there any way at all to figure out the source of the click in step 2?  This is for advertising analytics - we want to know where our clicks are coming from.

I know that the site visited in step 1 can theoretically retrieve device data and link it up to device data retrieved by the app.  However, we're looking for a more direct approach.

I've had a great deal of difficulty locating information on this, so any assistance would be appreciated.

We're using the Flurry API on IOS and Android.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you know about Google's offering: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns. Not sure if that is direct enough or if Google is an option.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can check the touchEvent point location, when the ad bannber frame rect contains the touchpoint , we can treat that as a click ad event.

Comment: True, we would use that for tracking the click on the ad itself.  Unfortunately, all that does is notify us that a user has, indeed clicked our ad.  It doesn't confirm whether they installed or used the app.  My understanding is that Apple's separation of data spaces makes this impossible.